# Emotion recognition from speech

Tags: machine-learning, voice

What would be a method for obtaining the emotion of a given person using tonal analysis of the person's speech? I can find many research papers on this subject but there seems to be a lack of programs that shows the implementation other than many closed source APIs that are made available to users with restrictions.

Is such a method possible? What are the problems that might be faced for such a task?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in audio analysis, but I had some experience in the field. The process of emotion recognition from speech is very much the same as in every classification task. You have to extract the features of the emotions from the speech and then classify. There are available databases of [emotional speech](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.98.9202&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and also audio analysis libraries for [feature extraction](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki/3.-Feature-Extraction). You can use them to build your dataset.

3 years ago I implemented it to distinguish angry speech from not angry. I also searched through the internet for available APIs and there are a few, but they are not working really. Mostly it's only a research topic but not something which can be used to solve real life problems.

There are a lot of problems in this field, for example:

- The test voice was recorded with a different device.
- There is too much noise in the sound.
- The men and women has very different voices.

[Here](https://webempath.net/lp-eng/) is a solution what you can try in your browser.

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for the late reply(Changed PC and forgot the password that was recovered recently :P).BTW can you tell me which features are to be extracted for classification?Would LDA or SVM be better for classification?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BeyondVerbal's API](http://www.beyondverbal.com/api/), I've been using it for a few years with good success for an app that tests candidates for telesales jobs ([FindClosers.com](https://www.findclosers.com/) - still under dev).   It lets you not only get emotion, but get the underlying components under it - valence, polarity, energy, etc.   Here's a screenshot of what someone's enoyment, or "valence" looks like mapped out of the course of 25 telephone calls:

[image]

They offer a free trial and free level of their API, so it's great to play with.

Comment: It seems like  BeyondVerbal is not providing service as a API now

Comment: They are, they're just charging $1000 per month for it.   Check out https://www.deepaffects.com/apis/

Comment: deepaffect doesn't provide pricing plans. @DoughB

Comment: it must be free then! :)  that's certainly annoying though.

Comment: Seems like not free. charges is 3000$ per month for 100000 minutes  deepaffects.